# ParseException line 5:19 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'MIN' '(' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am running below query on hive

```
SELECT 
  a.NDC,
  a.filetag,
  b.filetag AS filetag_RMIID1,
  a.medid,
  b.MED_REF_FED_LEGEND_IND,
  b.MED_MEDID_DESC
FROM 
  TMPTBL_RMINDC1_MERGED_SORTED_ND a
  INNER JOIN TMPTBL_RMIID1_MERGED_SORTED_ND b ON a.medid = b.medid
WHERE 
  b.filetag = (SELECT MIN(c.filetag) FROM TMPTBL_RMIID1_MERGED_SORTED_ND c WHERE c.medid = a.medid AND c.filetag >= a.filetag)
```

and getting below error

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 
5:19 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'MIN' '(' in expression 
specification (state=42000,code=40000)
```

please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive supports only `IN/NOT IN, EXISTS/NOT EXISTS` in where clause sub query. In your query replace where condition with below and it should work:

```
b.filetag in (SELECT MIN(c.filetag) FROM TMPTBL_RMIID1_MERGED_SORTED_ND c 
WHERE c.medid = a.medid AND c.filetag >= a.filetag)
```

More details on hive subquery support can be found here:
[Hive Subqueries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause)

Comment: Thanks @jainik for answer, also I have made correction in inner query as 
WHERE b.filetag in (
SELECT MIN(c.filetag) FROM TMPTBL_RMIID1_MERGED_SORTED_ND c inner join TMPTBL_RMINDC1_MERGED_SORTED_ND d on c.medid = d.medid WHERE c.medid = d.medid AND c.filetag >= d.filetag)

now it is working.